# Force heroku to use a specific version of Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I've written a node.js app that works great locally, but when I push to heroku, I get the following error:

```
2012-04-11T00:42:55+00:00 app[web.1]:         throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
2012-04-11T00:42:55+00:00 app[web.1]:         ^
2012-04-11T00:42:55+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'isArray'
```

I've figured out that heroku's Node is v0.4.7, but mine locally is v0.6.3. I'm specifying to use v0.6.3 in my package.json file:

```
"engine": {  
    "node": "0.6.3"  
  , "npm": "1.1.9"
}
```

But that's obviously not doing anything, even after I push.

This has been bothering me all day, and all I need to do is figure out how to get the `util.isArray()` [method](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.3/api/util.html#util.isArray) working again (hopefully). That's the error I'm getting, and it's because that's not supported in v0.4.7 of node.

Comment: If all else fails, you can use `if (arr instanceof Array)` to determine if `arr` is an array.

Comment: Hey @CaseyChu, I know - I just don't want to do that because it's a NPM module that's giving this error, and I don't want to have to clone the module, use a relative version of it, etc. It'd be much more convenient to make node be the correct version I want.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you're using `engine` instead of `engines` per [the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-versions), which would result in the default `0.4.7` version being applied.

Comment: interesting, I didn't see that -- especially since *it's not an answer.* Thanks for penalizing me for trying to help future Googlers.